# WPF ListView resizing madness

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, resize

I am trying to resize a `ListView` in WPF. I want to figure out how to force a `ListView` to shrink its width to only fit the width of its columns.  I have a `ListView` that I bind using the View property and add some `GridViewColumn`s like so:

```
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width={Binding NameWidth} DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Fee" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Fee}"/>

                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

I bind the width of the column so that I can hide/unhide the column. When I unhide a column the `ListView` grows to accommodate the new width. But when I hide the column again the `ListView`'s width doesn't shrink.

I have tried to subclass the `ListView` and call some commands like

`InvalidateArrange()`, `InvalidateMeasure()`, `InvalidateVisual()`. But none of them cause the `ListView` to shrink.

If I reload the Collection to the `ListView` it does shrink to fit. But I think that is not elegant, nor the right way to do it. I have journeyed through Reflector to find myself in a quagmire of confusion. Can someone give me some insight?

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView is likely being sized by its parent container, not by its contents.  For example, a Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel, Border, etc., outside your ListView may be stretching your ListView to fill its width.

If this does not solvethe problem, please test your ListView in an empty Window with a root WrapPanel to factor out any other surrounding XAML in your control and post the entire XAML for that Window.